# Как сравнить две даты в php, если одна из них раньше 01.01.1970

Tags: php

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что у меня есть две даты: сегодняшняя и введенная пользователем и мне понадобилось их сравнить.Сам код выглядит следующим образом:

```
$tim = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))-strtotime($_POST['_bt']);
```

Но проблема в том, что если дата находящаяся в $_POST['_bt'] раньше 1.1.1970, то вывода просто не происходит.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте стандартный [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) и предоставьте калькуляцию дат ему. Не говоря о том, что этот класс удобнее и нагляднее ручного управления таймштампом.

```
$userInput = \Datetime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_POST['_bt']);
if (! $userInput) {
// todo user input invalid date
}

var_dump($userInput->diff(new \datetime()));
```

Для простого сравнения на больше-меньше `DateTime` реализует и соответствующие операторы.

```
if ($userInput > new \DateTime) {
    // дата из будущего
}
```

Comment: Мне не совсем то нужно.
Мне нужно найти сколько лет прошло с той даты, которую ввел пользователь, я это делаю таким образом:
if (floor($live / (60*60*24*366)) <= 5){ //тут код
} 
Но я не могу ввести дату длительностью больше 46 лет!

Comment: Используйте данный ответ, вы можете вывести количество лет через функцию format - echo $userInput->diff(new DateTime())->format('%Y% лет'); соответственно документации http://php.net/manual/ru/dateinterval.format.php